# Use hidden API without reflection in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I develop application for my custom ROM and I need to call PackageManager's method which are annotated like this:

```
      /* 
      @hide
      */
      public abstract void deletePackage(
          String packageName, IPackageDeleteObserver observer, int flags);
```

I guess it's all about another android.jar. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Check out [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/) to see how to use hide API without reflection. Note that in order to use this special one, you need DELETE_PACKAGES permission whcih requires root privilege.

Comment: @yorkw I guess root privileges won't grant this permission.

Comment: @yorkw "1) Android is an open source project. We can download the source code and customize build system so it does not exclude internal & hidden classes from android.jar. This is a hard way." - that's what I want to do. It's better then ADT modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with building custom SDK, where I removed annotations.